# MySQL 8 crashes subselect query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, mysql-8.0

Why is this query crashes in MySql 8 but works fine in Mysql 5?

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `sports` 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *, 
                      (SELECT `id` 
                       FROM   `sport_events` 
                       WHERE  `tournament_id` = `tournaments`.`id` 
                              AND `status` = ? 
                              AND `sport_events`.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
                       ORDER  BY `created_at` DESC 
                       LIMIT  1) AS `live_event_id` 
               FROM   `tournaments` 
               WHERE  `sports`.`id` = `tournaments`.`sport_id`)
```

The query part that causes the crash is this nested subselect

```
(SELECT `id` 
   FROM   `sport_events` 
   WHERE  `tournament_id` = `tournaments`.`id` 
          AND `status` = ? 
          AND `sport_events`.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
   ORDER  BY `created_at` DESC 
   LIMIT  1) AS `live_event_id`
```

Comment: Can you show us your table schema

Comment: Does it crash at prepare or execute/open/fetch?

Comment: BTW, that EXISTS can be simplified as `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM   tournaments 
               WHERE  sports.id = tournaments.sport_id)`.

Answer (score 0):

you asked the question 2 days ago in MySQL Community Slack and you got 10 replies asking for some details. We are still waiting....